# can't POST data with Flask app using SQLAlchemy + Marshmallow

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to POST some data to a database on AWS RDS. I have a Flask application, and I am trying to commit a SQLAlchemy object to the db.

here is a sqlalchemy class with 3 fields, and the accompanying marshmallow schema class :

```
class Plant(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    dur = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    def __init__(self, name, dur):
        self.name = name
        self.dur = dur

class PlantSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Plant
```

Here is the a POST request in app.py, in order to add a plant model to my database :

```
plant_schema = PlantSchema()

@app.route('/plants', methods=['POST'])
def add_plant():
    name = request.json.get('name', '')
    dur = request.json.get('dur', '')
    plant = Plant(name=name, dur=dur)
    db.session.add(plant)
    db.session.commit()
    return plant_schema.jsonify(plant)
```

unfortunately, when i POST my request in Postman, i get the following

```
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not &#x27;application/json&#x27;.</p>
```

this is the JSON that i am giving to postman, for the POST request.

```
{
    "name":"melon", 
    "dur":"1"
}
```

not sure where i went wrong, im not sure if the JSON is correctly structured, but i dont know the proper structure it should have, or where in the application the post is breaking down.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in your request that you are sending a json.

If you send without Content-Type, your application will return that you need to specify the `Content-Type` to `application/json`:

[image: no content type informed]

You just need to add the content type header:

[image: with content type in header]

Code for the example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.post("/")
def teste():
    a = request.json.get("teste", "")

    return a, 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```